# what does this rewrite actually do?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

im confused as to what this does....

what does the REQEUST_URI do ?

Comment: Read the documentation for RewriteCond: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (`RewriteCond`) the requested URI starts with `/new/`, the script `new.php` is called (`RewriteRule`). It will be passed the requested URI as the `title` parameter, the query string (if any) will be preserved (the `QSA` flag), and no further rules will be processed after this one (the `L` flag).

i.e.

- `http://example.com/new/test.html` would call `http://example.com/new.php?title=/new/test.html`
- `http://example.com/new/test2.html?query=test3` would call `http://example.com/new.php?title=/new/test2.html&query=test3`

Answer (score 0):

If the URL begins with "/new/", it rewrites the URL to new.php, placing the old URL as the value for the "title" field.

"/new/Foo+Bar?bam=bug-AWWK!" becomes "new.php?title=/new/Foo+Bar&bam=bug-AWWK!" or (if the RewriteRule is in an .htaccess file) "new.php?title=new/Foo+Bar&bam=bug-AWWK!".

Answer (score 0):

Basically it makes nice, pretty URLs.

It takes an URL like http:/www.example.org/new/foobar and in the background calls http://www.example.org/new.php?title=foobar.

REQUEST_URI is everything after the hostname. In the above example that's /new/foobar.

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be explained as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/new/
```

If the URL request is your hostname (REQUEST_URI) follow by `new` folder...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then rewrite them as your hostname follow by provided string `new.php?title=` and end with variables after `/new/` in original URL request.

Example: URL request to:

```
http://yoursite.com/new/orange
```

server will interpret it as:

```
http://yoursite.com/new.php?title=orange
```

Answer (score 0):

*REQEUST_URI* contains the current [absolute URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). So the rule will be applied on every request that’s URL path starts with `/new/…` and rewrites/redirects it internally to the *new.php* file in the current directory (assuming that you didn’t change the base URL path with `RewriteBase`).

So if you use this rule in the .htaccess file of

- your document root directory (`/`), a request of `/new/foo/bar` would be rewritten/redirected to `/new.php?title=new/foo/bar`.
- `/new/` , a request of `/new/foo/bar` would be rewritten/redirected to `/new/new.php?title=foo/bar`.
- `/new/foo`, the request would be rewritten/redirected to `/new/foo/new.php?title=bar`.